# DataTables in Codeigniter (display million rows of data)

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, datatables, odbc

I created a DataTable in codeigniter and it's already working with small amount of data but I want to run the project with 1 Million rows of data. Unfortunately, it is not working with this huge amount of data.

What should I add/change in my code below?
I'm using codeigniter, oracle database and odbc driver

Thank you!

```js
//JavaScript

    <script>

 $('#user-list').DataTable({
    
  "processing": true,
 
 
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ],
          
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Reports/get_User,
            type : 'GET'
        },
         

         "aoColumns": [
          { "data": "ID" },
          { "data": "FirstName" },  
          { "data": "LastName" },
          { "data": "Address"},
          { "data": "Email" },
  
                      
            ]
      
    });

</script>
```

```html
//html

  <table id="user-list" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

```html
 //controller
 
 public function get_User()
   {
      $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
      $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
      $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    

      $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); 

      
      $data = [];



      foreach($query->result() as $r) {
           $data[] = array(
                $r-ID
                $r-FirstName,
                $r-LastName,
                $r-Address,
            $r-Email,
                $r_tab[] = $r


           );
      }

      $result = array(
               "draw" => $draw,
                 "recordsTotal" => $query->num_rows(),
                 "recordsFiltered" => $query->num_rows(),
                 "data" => $data,
                  "data" =>  $r_tab

            );
      echo json_encode($result);
      exit();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? You get an explicit error / your request times out / other failure type ?

Comment: The request times out.

Comment: you should use ajax for getting specific amount of data instead of all rows. data table usually hides other rows and show 10 pages. but browser cant't take pressure of huge data

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing your own server by attempting to load in memory a huge amount of data.

Check this [server-side processing (5,000,000 rows) DataTable sample](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) - unfortunately, this example does not use a real database connection to retrieve the data, but it is still informative.

In essence, you need to alter your AJAX request to include an `offset` and `limit`, values that need to be added to your query in order to retrieve from the database only the data to be displayed instead of the whole table.

Try this:

1. Alter your AJAX call to look like this:

```js
        scrollY: 200, 
        "ajax": function ( data, callback, settings ) {
            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Reports/get_User/" + data.start + "/" + data.length,
            type : 'GET'
        },
```

2. Alter your controller like this (you may need to adjust your routes too):

```php
// Be sure to validate that $offset and $limit are valid numeric values (integer, positive, limit does not exceed a certain value, etc)
public function get_User($offset, $limit)
{
    $limit = (int) $limit;
    $offset = (int) $offset;

    ...
    
    // Not sure about the "LIMIT" syntax for Oracle, please look it up
    $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $offset, $limit"); 

    ...
```

**Note**: These code snippets are not perfect (I have not worked with DataTable before) but they should help you get on the right track.

Comment: Regarding row limiting syntax, Oracle 12c introduced `OFFSET` / `FETCH` like: `SELECT last_name FROM employees ORDER BY last_name OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :maxnumrows ROWS ONLY`.  Use bind variables (as shown) for performance and security. For earlier Oracle versions check out `ROWNUM` on p 181 'Limiting Rows and Creating Paged Datasets' of Oracle's free [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf).